# Shell scripting : split an output and assign it to different variables

Tags: shell, variables, eval, output

I have an output of a command/script as below...

63-19:48:47

I want a script to read it and print it as 63days 19hours 48mins 47seconds.

If it is just 19:48:47, then I want the same script  to print as 19hours 48mins 47seconds.

Is there a way to split the output and assign it to different variables to achieve the abouve results or thru some other emans?...Please help me out.

Comment: Which shell are your using? bash?

Comment: SHELL=/bin/ksh. Please let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo 63-19:48:47 | tr ':-' ' ' |read a b c d
```

Or if number of parameters is not strict (3 or 4):

```
set `echo 63-19:48:47 | tr ':-' ' '`
if [ -z "$4" ]
then
  day="$1"
  shift
fi
hour="$1"
min="$2"
sec="$3"
```

Comment: tr: Not a recognized flag: :
tr: 0653-712 The combination of options and String parameters is not legal.
Usage: tr [ -[c|C] | -[c|C]ds | -[c|C]s | -ds | -s ] [-A] String1 String2
       tr { -[c|C]d | -[c|C]s | -d | -s } [-A] String1

Comment: I am getting the above output

Comment: I used the same as above. My output was for above

Comment: I'm sorry! I've made a typo. Please see my edit and note that now it is `:-`, not `-:`. I'm sorry once again